# How to show MessageBox in Asp.Net based on conditions given in the Server side code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have found so many questions in Stack Overflow based on "Displaying Message Box in Asp.Net".

But is it possible to check the condition in the button click event and to display MessageBox if the Condition is true? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Yes, you can check your condition in the PAGE LOAD event and set the visible propertie of the message box at this time..
If you want the condition can be set in a session variable and the message box can be written in the master page. Like this you just have to set the condition to true from everywhere when you decide that the message have to be visible.

***After Question edition :***

Yes you can, just catch the button_click event do verification stuff...

Aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnValid" runat="server" Text="Valid" OnClick="btn_click" />
```

Code Behind (C#)

```
  public void btn_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Verification Stuff and set the messageBox visibility

    }
```

Comment: It could be worth to remind that if you cast the sender object to Button you`ll get every data from the button wich trigered the event!